# PHP New Line from Java Delimiter?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I saw lots of questions about how to use PHP new line delimiters but none really addressing the problem I have. So I have Contact information that is acquired from a Java program using the `\n` delimiter that is nicely stored with new lines functioning properly in a TEXT column in my MySQL database, appearing like so:

```
First Name:AT&T Check Bill Balance
 Phone number:*225#

 First Name:AT&T Customer Care
 Phone number:1-800-331-0500
```

However when using PHP to call the text to display in the browser using:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($ContactList, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

To display all the data stored in the field, it appears as a sloppy blob of texts with no new lines like so:

> First Name:AT&T Check Bill Balance Phone number:*225# First Name:AT&T Customer Care Phone number:1-800-331-0500

Is there anyway to fix this just using PHP or am I going to have to clear the data, go back to the Java Program, use the PHP delimiter instead and then resend the information?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. You probably meant `\n` not `/n`. 2. Storing multiple values in one field in the DB is *never* a good idea.

Comment: Are you trying to output this as HTML or something else?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. Also, I'm a noob in database development and am really just messing around trying to learn. What are some of the problems that could come about with storing multiple values in one field? Here I only plan to display the contacts list as a whole, never would I have a case asking for a single contact.

Comment: And I want the result output to be displayed in a browser using HTML, yes.

Comment: if the text that is saved to the database includes newlines. you can print it with `nl2br()`

Comment: `\n` is a fine way to separate multiple lines of text in a string, regardless of the language you're using (Java, PHP, etc.) but it's intentionally not how web pages work. You might want to read up more on how and why HTML collapses whitespace. `nl2br` is a perfectly reasonable way to make line-breaks show up in a browser, but it's a bit of a blunt solution. Depending on what you're trying to do with this text, you may want to do something different.

Answer (score 1):

php displays it in a webpage, so a webpage will not display the newline characters as a new line.  You would have to put in some css or "less than symbol" br "greater than symbol" to enter a new line where you want to create a new line.